# PHP PDO bindParam was falling in a foreach

Tags: php, pdo

I had a loop like that :

```
foreach($Fields as $Name => $Value){
    $Query->bindParam(':'.$Name, $Value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
```

Nothing complicated. However, each value was set to the last one in the array (`$Fields`).

How can I fix that ?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

However, thanks to this [guys](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.bindparam.php#98145). I found out that you need to pass the value by reference with a `&` before like that :

```
foreach($Fields as $Name => &$Value){
    $Query->bindParam(':'.$Name, $Value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
```

This was driving me nuts.

Actual quote from [PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.bindparam.php#98145) :

> Vili 28-May-2010 12:01
>
> This works ($val by reference):

```
<?php
foreach ($params as $key => &$val){
    $sth->bindParam($key, $val);
}
?>
```

> This will fail ($val by value, because bindParam needs &$variable):

```
<?php
foreach ($params as $key => $val) {
    $sth->bindParam($key, $val);
}
?>
```

Comment: Correct answer, but unfortunately, not working if you need to bind the key value too. In this case, you will need to create an array with the key. Use array_keys

Answer (score 9):

If you don't need the ability to keep the variable in sync with the bound parameter before the query is executed (which is the case 99.9% of the time, in my experience), it's probably better to simply use [`PDOStatement::bindValue()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) instead of [`PDOStatement::bindParam()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php):

```
foreach ($Fields as $Name => $Value) {
    $Query->bindValue(':' . $Name, $Value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I knew it about this. That why I was using the bindParam, there's some change going on later on the script. And I am using bindValue was too often that to knew that bindParam was requiring a &.