# PHP PDO bindValue() binds null instead of value

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

i am trying to convert my code from pgsql to PDO+postgres, and have a problem with the binding of the values to a prepared statement, i found debugDumpParams, but there seems to be no way to show the fully prepared statement (with inserted values)?
anyway, here's what i tryed:

```
if(is_array($args) && count($args) >0) foreach($args as $key => $val) 
{
       if(!preg_match("/^:/",$key)) $key = ":$key";
       print("binding $key to ".var_export($val,true)."<br\n>");
       if(!is_null($structure))
       {
         if(!$stmt->bindValue($key, $val, $structure[$key])) print("failed to bind '$key = $val' as ".$structure[$key]." to ".print_r($stmt,true)."<br>\n");
       }   
      else if(!$stmt->bindValue($key, $val)) print("failed to bind '$key = $val' to ".print_r($stmt,true)."<br>\n");
     }
     
     try
     {
       $stmt->debugDumpParams( );
       $result = $stmt->execute();
     }
```

and i get :

```
 binding :name to 'toto'<br>
 binding :title to 'titi'<br>
 binding :stitle to 'default'<br>
 binding :style to NULL<br>
 binding :notitle to false<br>
 binding :nofooter to false<br>
 binding :visible to false<br>
 binding :acl to NULL<br>
 SQL: [157] INSERT INTO pages (name, title, stitle, style, notitle, nofooter, visible, acl) 
               VALUES (:name, :title, :stitle, :style, :notitle, :nofooter, :visible, :acl);
 Params:  8
 Key: Name: [5] :name paramno=0 name=[5] ":name" is_param=1 param_type=0
 Key: Name: [6] :title paramno=1 name=[6] ":title" is_param=1 param_type=0
 Key: Name: [7] :stitle paramno=2 name=[7] ":stitle" is_param=1 param_type=0 
 Key: Name: [6] :style paramno=3 name=[6] ":style" is_param=1 param_type=0
 Key: Name: [8] :notitle paramno=4 name=[8] ":notitle" is_param=1 param_type=0
 Key: Name: [9] :nofooter paramno=5 name=[9] ":nofooter" is_param=1 param_type=0
 Key: Name: [8] :visible paramno=6 name=[8] ":visible" is_param=1 param_type=0
 Key: Name: [4] :acl paramno=7 name=[4] ":acl" is_param=1 param_type=0

 <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 
   ERROR:  null value in column &quot;name&quot; violates not-null constraint
   DETAIL:  Failing row contains (13, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null). in /var/www/html/cs/libs/PDOUsers.php:267
```

what's baffling, is that the bind (and i tryed both by value first, and now by parameter) returns an all ok, whilst the bound values, are evidently all set to null (besides the id which is of type serial)....

if i copy the query and replace the placeholders with the before mentioned values and input that into psql, all runs fine...
since i don't see any of the supposedly bound data in the error detail, so what is happening?

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144557/php-pdo-bindparam-was-falling-in-a-foreach is worth a read.

Comment: well that's why i tryed first with bindValue since i din't want to run into that sort of problem.....  but even adding the passby reference, it still doesn't bind the values...

Comment: well... found it.... if the type is null, the bindValue doesn't raise an error and silently fails... not what i might expect as usual behaviour...